# I am unable to play a DVD

Tags: dvd

VERSION="20.04.3 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
Dell Latitude

I can see files on the CD Drive

When I click videos the player opens and I see this error..

Unable to play the file
DVD source is required to play the file, but is not installed.

Find in Ubuntu Software fails when I click on the button.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs <- This is required to play DVDs.

Answer (score 5):

Retail DVDs are usually encrypted and you need software to decrypt the DVD in order to play them.

To install the necessary library, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg && sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

With this library installed, you should be able to play encoded DVDs with media players like VLC and MPlayer.

If you'd like more information, see the wiki on [RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs).